# How to get the return value of a function in Access vba?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to replace several characters in a string with several other characters with the following function:

```
Public Function CharacterChange(S As String) As String
Dim A As String * 1
Dim B As String * 1
Dim i As Integer

Const AccChars = "°é*±äöüßaaŐŰú#~Mµ"
Const RegChars = "DEX+aousaaouudcMU"

For i = 1 To Len(AccChars)
A = Mid(AccChars, i, 1)
B = Mid(RegChars, i, 1)
S = Replace(S, A, B)

Next

CharacterChange = S

Exit Function
End Function
```

Then I call the function here:

```
Private Sub ButtonClick()
...
CharacterChange(MyText)
...
End Sub
```

But it seems I don't get back the result of the function, after calling it I still see my original text with the special characters. What is wrong, please advise.

Comment: Can you share a sample of the input and expected output of your function? Also a sample of what you're getting now.

Comment: For example i want to clear this text: "Accessory kit for some product - 90°, #2". In the function I see that the value of S is  "Accessory kit for some product - 90D, D2", but if I check MyText value after CharacterChange(MyText), it is still the original "Accessory kit for some product - 90°, #2".

Comment: `NewText = CharacterChange(MyText)`

Comment: Thanks Andre, simple but great. At first I got byref argument type mismatch, but a proper variable declaration solved it too.